# Python - Extract URLs from email messages

Tags: python, email, extract

I've been stuck on this for days, and have no idea which module to use. What I want to set up is a python script where you just enter the path to an email message as an argument, and then the script extracts all URLs within the message. I've tried using the email, email.parser, etc. modules, but nothing seems to do what I need. I'm still somewhat new a python so reading the documentation is a little confusing. Any guidance or suggestions would be appreciated. I can work on the regex or another method for searching URLs, just need to know how to display the message body. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post  sample email content with urls?

Comment: As @Rakesh mentioned, if you post the email content with the URL's with your attempt at a `regex` (or other) solution, will be more than happy to give you some pointers.

Comment: I shouldn't since these are work emails. How can I read the body of a email message or view the message source?

Answer (score 2):

If you've already done the work to fetch the email and have it as a string in python, then try [this regex](http://urlregex.com):

```
import re

email = '<email text here> Maybe I have a URL like http://cnn.com or maybe it is something more complex like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49654499/python-extract-urls-from-email-messages'
# email = "http://cnn.com"
regex = 'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+'

match = re.findall(regex, email)

for m in match:
    print(m)
```

Output:

```
$ python3 email.py 
http://cnn.com
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49654499/python-extract-urls-from-email-messages
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple regex statement:

```
import re

def get_url (email):
    return re.search(r'\@.+',email).group(0)[1:]
```

This *should* return the domain name the email address is from.

Comment: See my other comments, I want to be able to read or print the message body first, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would suffice:

```
import re

def get_urls(message): ## message is a string

    (1) Use a regex to find all substrings beginning
        with 'http' and ending in whitespace
    (2) Return these.  This may contain more strings than
        you want, so you will need to manually inspect them.
```

If you post an attempt at solving the solution, I csan post more specific code.  This is enough to get you started on your own implementation.

Comment: How can I read/print the message body? That's the part I'm stuck on.

Comment: Are we talking about an actual email from an account?  That's more nuanced.  I know gmail has a way that you can programatically access your emails via access credentials.  Generally speaking, each host has a different procedure for how you retrieve emails from them

Comment: Not from an acocunt, I just want to save a message to my computer, then use the path as an argument in the script to take care of the rest.

Comment: assuming you copy pasted the content into '/tmp/myemail.txt', you can open the file and get the contents via: `message = ''.join(open('/tmp/myemail.txt').readlines())`

Comment: Hm, that's starting to look better. I think I was having issues because of encoding maybe? I was saving as a ".msg" file instead of text. What about links in HTML messages?

Comment: Links in html are trickier because oftentimes it's relative to the current page you're on (ex: if I'm at www.example.com, there might be a link to www.example.com/help, but in the page it's probably listed as '/help' or 'help'.   To get these links, you need to search the html tags for hrefs or action attributes, then append these to the end of the page link

Comment: For instance, when I was inspecting the source code for this question, I saw this: `href="/users/4343502/touch-my-boom-boom"`.  This link on it's own isn't a website, but if you add `https://www.stackoverflow.com` to the front it becomes valid.